# How to get physical file path of `manifests.xml` in android?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

Below code is used for read manifest relative path.

```
    final String BUILD_OUTPUT = "build/intermediates";
    final FileFsFile manifest;

    if (FileFsFile.from(BUILD_OUTPUT, "manifests").exists()) {
        manifest = FileFsFile.from(BUILD_OUTPUT, "manifests", "full", flavor, type, "AndroidManifest.xml");
    } else {
        manifest = FileFsFile.from(BUILD_OUTPUT, "bundles", flavor, type, "AndroidManifest.xml");
    }
```

Instead of relative path, Let me know how to get manifest physical path

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you